# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error got fixed by restarting the nginx server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

When I hit my application url, I got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error, and when I googled about it, this issue might be because of nginx misconfiguration, however we did not change anything in the nginx configuration. Then, I tried restarting my nginx server, and then I stopped getting the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. When I googled about it, I got the below reasons, Misconfigured WordPress settings
Misconfigured WordPress plugin.
Misconfigured server settings.
Incorrect HTTPS settings.
Issues with the browser’s cache/cookies.
Issues with third-party services (e.g. CDNs).
Improper website or domain migration., however we did not make any such configurations.  The issue got resolved just by restarting the nginx server. May I know if there be any other reason for too many redirects issue.

Note: Another reason can be Cached redirect: If a redirect is cached, it can cause redirects to loop endlessly. Clear the cache to resolve the issue.
May I know when a redirect gets cached?